# Sublime Text 2: subl shell command often fails to open files

Tags: shell, sublimetext2

I have Sublime Text 2 installed on a Mac, and have made a link on the command line [as described in the docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html).

When opening files from the terminal, as in:

```
$ subl foo.txt
```

A Sublime Text window will open, but inside that window foo.txt will only open about one out of every three times or so. I've tried moving the link to a different folder in the path, creating it with sudo, etc., but no luck so far.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem for a while now. Add the following line to your .bash_profile:

```
alias subl='subl && sleep 0.1 && subl'
```

Now you can use `subl filename_to_edit` to open it.

If you are not sure if you configured `subl` command correctly, do the following. Run the first command for ST3 or the second for ST2:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Make sure that ~/bin is in your $PATH. Then do the first step with .bash_profile.

Finally works as it should! Credit goes to [these guys](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/62343-subl-with-no-window-open-doesnt-open-the-file/) and chrisf for improvement.

Comment: Nice, that actually does it.
On a side note, I think `alias subl='subl && sleep 0.1 && subl'` works perfectly fine. If you run into any trouble with that, `alias subl='\subl && sleep 0.1 && \subl'` should bypass any existing aliases.

Comment: Wow. You still had the same problem for 2 years?

Comment: I actually thought it was fixed for a while, because I never really ran into the issue, but then I've had it happen to me a couple times recently.

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into problems with subl before. And had to come up with a function to see if Sublime is running, if not launch it, see if it loaded. Then use "rmate" bash script and the associated "rsub" Sublime Text Package plugin to load in the specified file. However you should be able to use the OSX open command should work for what you need. I would also give the latest Sublime Text 3 Beta a try.